rename key in array of objects using javascript
I have a simple array of objects as shown below
let input = [
    { "p1": [ 1, 0 ] },
    { "p2": [ 1, 6 ] },
    { "total": [ 0, 4 ] },
    { "p3plus": [ 0, 2 ] }
]

All i want to do is just rename the keys of this array of objects. so my final output should be as shown below. Basically i am renaming p1, p2, p3plus and total with P1, P2, P3+ and Total.
let output = [
    { "P1": [ 1, 0 ] },
    { "P2": [ 1, 6 ] },
    { "Total": [ 0, 4 ] },
    { "P3+": [ 0, 2 ] }
]

I tried the following code
const output = input.map(({
  p1: P1,
  p2: P2,
  p3plus: P3+,
  total: Total,

  ...rest
}) => ({
  P1,
  P2,
  P3+, 
  Total, 
  ...rest
}));

This code doesnot work primarily because i am trying to put P3+ and it errors out during compilation. Even if i skip renaming p3plus, the output is not as expected because it keeps adding undefined to the final output. Can someone point to me where i am going wrong
Here is the error 
also, if i dont rename p3Plus and go ahead and rename other two, i see undefined objects which are not needed. how can i eliminate getting those undefined objects


it errors out during compilation.; what's the error message?

in your mapping attempt, what are P1, P2, P3 (which is an invalid variable name, by the way), Total?

added error image to question

You didn't add anything to p3; the comma is unexpected because you're missing the other addend.

+ is an operator, it's not valid as part of a variable/property name

JavaScript doesn’t allow special characters like + in variable names

i know + is considering as an addition here. but how do i rename it to P3+ is the question. also the output has undefined in the result for other key renames

@mykaf- you are reiterating what i already know and its not helpful when kept repeating. i have got the answer anyway from Nina.

@mykaf It is a perfectly valid property name in an object.

@fdomn-m Wrong for property names.

@connexo technically, you can do x["p3+"] = true, but you can't do let x = { "P3+" : true };  console.log(x.P3+); - so it's arguable whether that makes it "valid" for a property name if you can't use them as property names.   Either way - I hope you'll agree it's a bad idea!

Nope, not a bad idea. You can always access the property by using the bracket notation as well. console.log(x["P3+"]). These are perfectly normal things to do in JS.

You could take an object for the replacements and map the single objects with replaced properties.


const
    input = [{ "p1": [ 1, 0 ] }, { "p2": [ 1, 6 ] }, { "total": [ 0, 4 ] }, { "p3plus": [ 0, 2 ] }],
    replacements = { p1: 'P1', p2: 'P2', total: 'Total', p3plus: 'P3+' },
    result = input.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(o)
        .map(([k, v]) => [replacements[k] || k, v])
    ));

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




slighlty unclear about it. can you please elaborate or modify the code i have

You cannot rename the destructured p3plus variable P3+, since a plus sign (+) is not a legal variable name character.
You will need to assign it via: { 'P3+': p3plus }


const input = [
  { "p1"     : [ 1, 0 ] },
  { "p2"     : [ 1, 6 ] },
  { "total"  : [ 0, 4 ] },
  { "p3plus" : [ 0, 2 ] }
];

const output = input.map(({
  p1: P1,
  p2: P2,
  p3plus, // Keep as `p3plus` for now...
  total: Total,
  ...rest
}) => ({
  P1,
  P2,
  'P3+': p3plus, // Re-key here, since the '+' is not a valid variable name
  Total, 
  ...rest
}));

console.log(...output.map(JSON.stringify));
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



Here is a modified version of Nina's code for clarity:


const renameKeys = (objArr, keyReplacements) => {
  return objArr.map(obj => {
    const entries = Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([originalKey, originalValue]) => [
        keyReplacements[originalKey] ?? originalKey,
        originalValue
      ]);
    return Object.fromEntries(entries); // Back to object
  });
};

const input = [
  { "p1"     : [ 1, 0 ] },
  { "p2"     : [ 1, 6 ] },
  { "total"  : [ 0, 4 ] },
  { "p3plus" : [ 0, 2 ] }
];

const replacements = {
  p1     : 'P1',
  p2     : 'P2',
  total  : 'Total',
  p3plus : 'P3+'
};

const output = renameKeys(input, replacements);

console.log(...input.map(JSON.stringify));  // Before
console.log(...output.map(JSON.stringify)); // After
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



